# SQlite with hibernate in java

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

Can anyone share a working hibernate dialect for SQLite if there is one, and if not maybe a workaround? I tried this one `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use below maven dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SQLite database JDBC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

or you can use another sqlite  library

1-add repository in the pom.xml file(between the repositories tag)

```
<repository>
  <id>hibernatesqlite-maven</id>
  <url>https://hibernate-sqlite.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mavenrepo</url>
</repository>
```

2.add dependency in the pom.xml file(between the dependencies tag)

```
<!-- hibernate sqlite dialect -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.applerao</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernatesqlite</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3.modify the hibernate dialect configuration like:

```
<property name="dialect">com.applerao.hibernatesqlite.dialect.SQLiteDialect</property>
```

Comment: i tried with hibernate 5.2.2 Final and the same xerial version but it didnt work

Comment: what's the exception you are getting ?

Comment: name of the dialect couldnt be matched

Comment: I just modified the answer, can you please try 2nd process.